# creating small matrix from large matrix in r

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I have n x n type of matrix where `n = 100` or so.

```
mat <- matrix (1:10000, nrow=100)
rownames (mat) <- paste ("I", 1:100, sep = "")
colnames (mat)  <- paste ("I", 1:100, sep = "")
```

I want to select specific rows (or columns) and create a small n x n matrix.

```
# for example rows selected:
c(1, 20, 33, 44, 64).
```

Thus resulting matrix will loop like:

```
        I1   I20   I33   I44  I64
I1
I20
I33
I44
I64
```

Is there way to do so ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just select them directly via `[row,col]`

```
indices <- c(1, 20, 33, 44, 64)

mat[indices,indices]

> mat[indices,indices]
    I1  I20  I33  I44  I64
I1   1 1901 3201 4301 6301
I20 20 1920 3220 4320 6320
I33 33 1933 3233 4333 6333
I44 44 1944 3244 4344 6344
I64 64 1964 3264 4364 6364
```